# Cross Domain Auto Login

Tags: javascript, html, cross-domain, disqus, autologin

I'm implementing a plug-in that's embeddable in different sites like disqus.The plug-in is supposed to be embeddable in sites with different domain names whic I don't own. I would like to access user login status if user has already logged in an other site that is using my plug-in. I haven't able to find an answer to do this yet.

What I need is:

- If user logged in domain A.com that using my plug-in, user should be able to automatically login in other domain B.com which uses my plugin. (I don't own A.com and B.com)

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Due to CORS protection, if the server A or B don't allow cross domain request, you can't call them from the browser itself. It's a security feature.

If you want to do this and don't have access directly on A and B, you will have to use A and/or B API (if they exist) or use a C server as an intermediary for your requests.

Comment: How can we identify users with using a C server as an intermediary?

Answer (score 0):

Request header as well as server CROS prevention mechanism will not allow to login. Below is one of the solution to achive it.

**SSO** Single Sign ON, is one of the way by that we can come up with this problem. To achive **SSO** just create some service that will check for token (**token based authetication as well as we can check for coming url request**) and allow login (it is no where related to Windows, Forms authentication).

It's a kind of third party authentication mechanism, which will work basis of token based security and allow login.